# How to know the process id of current bash session?

Tags: linux, bash, session, process

I'm on a linux server and admin user. There're many admin users using this machine at the same time. So under current bash command line, how to know the current process id of the bash process I'm using?

Thanks!

Comment: `echo $$` or `echo $BASHPID`? See `man bash` for the difference.

Comment: Thanks @dramzy. I found $BASHPID indeed useful, as it "`differs from $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized`".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `echo $$` to get the *PID* of the current Bash shell you are using.